# React Native Timestamp query (firestore) not giving the right result

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I have an query sorting by timestamp,
and I need to see only the data within last week

so I did 
.dbRef
`.where('regTime', '>', new Date( -7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`

but somehow not filtered by correct results.

anyone knows why?

Comment: now I see in console log it gives me few years ago. so I did try to change to -7 also not correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seem to be less interesting / active programmers or people who like to help in react native,
so for future searchers:

```
let weekAgo = new Date();
let weekInMilliseconds = -7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
weekAgo.setTime(weekAgo.getTime() + weekInMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as accepted.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer